Is there a way initialize a matrix(2D array) with some default values(-1)
I was going through a dp problem, there I have to initialize the matrix with default(-1) values for memoized solution. And felt the need.
We can initialize the 1D array in java like this => Arrays.fill(arr, -1)
what for 2D array...?
Otherwise I have to run a nested for loop to initialize the matrix with default values, that includes more lines of code, and doesn't look appropriate when you are solving a dp problem.

Did you look at the source code for method fill in class Arrays? It contains a for loop, so in essence you are executing a loop even when you are initializing a one-dimensional array with that method.

Maybe you can adjust your algorithm such that you can make use of the default all-zeroes provided by new int[row][col] rather than doubly initialise the arrays.

It is a shame that Arrays.xxx() do not return the array as you could then have used matrix = setAll(new int[row][], i -> fill(new int[col], -1));

Yeah ofc, inbuilf function is going to use a for loop for Array.fill() method, but it reduces the code and functinality, so again for the matrix it will be something like nested for loop.

Try the approach below:
public void fill2D(int[][] matrix, int value) {
    int m = matrix.length;
    int n = matrix[0].length;
    for (int i = 0; i < m * n; i++) {
        int row = i / n;
        int col = i % n;
        matrix[row][col] = value;
    }
}

Usage:
@Test
public void test() {
    int[][] matrix = new int[5][6];
    fill2D(matrix, -1);
    for (int[] row : matrix) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}

Benchmark test
private final int M = 500;
private final int N = 500;

@Benchmark
public void method1() {
    int[][] matrix = new int[M][N];
    for (int i = 0; i < M * N; i++) {
        int row = i / N;
        int col = i % N;
        matrix[row][col] = -1;
    }
}

@Benchmark
public void method2() {
    int[][] matrix = new int[M][N];
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }
}

@Benchmark
public void method3() {
    int[][] matrix = new int[M][N];
    for (int[] row : matrix) {
        Arrays.fill(row, -1);
    }
}

Result
Benchmark              Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
BenchMarkTest.method1  avgt   20  0,600 ± 0,002  ms/op
BenchMarkTest.method2  avgt   20  0,191 ± 0,003  ms/op
BenchMarkTest.method3  avgt   20  0,216 ± 0,021  ms/op


Mabye I'm just still half asleep, but doesn't this perform the same number of operations (actually, more operations) than a simple (and easier to read) nested loop?

@FedericoklezCulloca I measured the time using a benchmark, and this is faster than two nested loops.

Please share your benchmark. I'm not saying you're lying, I'm actually curious.

You could combine Arrays.fill with Arrays.setAll using a function. Whether it is more readable or saves many lines compared to a simple loop is up to the viewer:
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int row = 4;
    int col = 4;
    int[][] matrix = new int[row][];

    IntFunction<int[]> func = i -> {
        int [] arr = new int[col];
        Arrays.fill(arr, -1);
        return arr;
    };

    Arrays.setAll(matrix, func::apply);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));

}

Or you can make use of streams and create your 2d array:
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int row = 4;
    int col = 4;

    int[][] matrixStream = IntStream.range(0, row).mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, col).map(j -> -1).toArray())
                                    .toArray(int[][]::new);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrixStream));
}

But under the hood, all approaches use a loop

Try This:
int[][] dp = new int[rows][cols];

for (int[] row : dp) {
   Arrays.fill(row, -1);
}

Full Code:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 5;
        int cols = 5;
        int[][] dp = new int[rows][cols];

        for (int[] row : dp) {
            Arrays.fill(row, -1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                System.out.print(dp[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

Output :
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 

